# Грамматический разбор "К нам обратилась женщина, по словам которой(,) их дом снесли"

Tags: синтаксис

***"К нам обратилась женщина, по словам которой(,) их дом снесли".***

(+)--
Во избежание лишних разговоров о какой-то грамматической некорректности (на основании семантической неоднозначности) даю другой вариант.

***"К нам обратилась женщина, по утверждению которой(,) её дом снесли незаконно".***

Или вот.

***"Мы обратились к английским ученым, по мнению которых(,) в этом предложении есть вводные слова***

(-)--

**Интересует для начала грамматическая структура предложения**. Конкретно, чем здесь является слово **"которой"** и весь оборот **"по словам которой"**. Запятая (после "которой") - это вопрос следующий.

*Обсуждается уже на нескольких форумах, все настолько увлеклись бескомпромиссными спорами вокруг запятой, что перестали суть замечать. Может, у нас получится попроще и попонятнее.*

//====================

Определения вводных слов (главное в них, детали опускаю).

1. (Школьное) Водные слова можно убрать из предложения, сохранив грамматику
2. (Университетское) Вводными называют слова и предложения, грамматически не связанные с общей структурой предложения... вводные слова не являются членами предложения.
3. (Академическое) Вводные слова - члены предложения, не имеющие синтаксической связи с остальными членами предложения...

Все различия - терминологические, вызваны только тем, считать ли вводные членом предложения (с нулевой синтаксической связью) или вовсе отказать им в этом. Для нас это совершенно не принципиально сейчас.
Если "которой" - союзное слово, то оно очевидно имеет синтаксическую связь и является членом предложения.

*Отсюда однозначный вывод. "По словам которой" - не вводные слова.
Ни в каком виде. Запятая на таком основании невозможна. А другой мотивации никто не выдвинул*.

Comment: Точно грамматического? Не синтаксического?

Comment: @Третийглаз Не понял вопроса. Во-первых, у меня нет формы "грамматического", во-вторых синтаксис - часть грамматики. Не вижу причин их противопоставлять тут. Термин "грамматический разбор" известен со школы. Если угодно (в силу каких-то новых веяний) назвать его "синтаксическим", я не против.

Answer (score 3):

Вводными называются слова, грамматически не связанные с членами предложения (т.е. не связанные с ними по способу согласования, управления или примыкания), не являющиеся членами предложения и выражающие отношение говорящего к высказываемой мысли, характеризующие способ ее оформления, источник сообщения  и т.п. Вводным словам присуща интонация вводности, выражающаяся в понижении голоса и более быстром их произнесении по сравнению с остальной частью предложения и в своеобразной безударности, что позволяет легко убрать их из предложения без изменения смысла самого предложения. В примечаниях указывается обычно, что вводными словами не являются союзы (союзные слова тоже выполняют роль союзов, значит, и они тоже).

"По словам которой", безусловно,указание на источник сообщения, но источник сообщения выражен союзным словом, входящим в состав придаточного определительного предложения в качестве элемента, указывающего на подчинённость второго предложения первому. Если его убрать, как мы это делаем с вводным словом, подчинительная связь разорвётся, у нас будут два не связанных между собой предложения:"К нам обратилась женщина, их дом снесли". Непонятно, чей их? Потеряна информация о связи дома и женщины. Можно передать эту связь с помощью бессоюзного предложения: "К нам обратилась женщина:их дом снесли".Но смысл изменился, появилась причинно-следственная связь: женщина обратилась к юристам, потому что их дом снесли.

Следовательно, сочетание не является вводным. А из этого уже следует, что не отделяется запятой от придаточного.

Answer (score 2):

Аналогичный пример рассмотрен у Розенталя (Справочник по русскому языку. Пунктуация):

> § 25.8. В зависимости от контекста одни и те же слова выступают то в
>   роли вводных слов (следовательно, не членов предложения), то в
>   качестве членов предложения.
>
> *Эти мысли высказаны в работах некоторых астрофизиков, по мнению
>   которых Вселенная неуклонно расширяется* (оборот *по мнению которых*
>   **нельзя выделить** в составе придаточной части сложноподчиненного
>   предложения). — **По мнению некоторых астрофизиков**,  *Вселенная неуклонно
>   расширяется*.

[Знаки препинания при словах, грамматически не связанных с членами предложения](https://orfogrammka.ru/OGL05/71827510.html)

**P.S.** Первоначальный ответ полностью изменён.

Comment: Не знаю, что у вас там выйдет, если вы телегу впереди лошади запряжете. Я просил начать с грамматического разбора. В зависимости от результата уже и будете ставить запятую,

Comment: Короче, если опустить ваше "если", вы настаиваете на том, что это вводной оборот?! ***Можно узнать на основании чего вы так решили? И каким определением пользовались?!***

Comment: (исходный вариант того же - из двух предложений, с явным присутствием вводного оборота) _К нам обратилась женщина. По словам оной, их дом снесли._ Не думаю, чтобы замена местомения _"оной"_ на _"которой"_ (и то, и другое ссылается на "женщину"), с последующим объединением двух предложений, привела к утрате вводного оборота: внутри него изменяется только способ указания на _источник_. Кроме того, данный оборот изымается без нарушения смысла предложения.

Comment: Alex_ander, не надо никаких исходных. И менять ничего не надо. При чем тут вообще местоимение? *Пожалуйста, объясните, почему вы считаете **"по словам которой"** вводным оборотом.* Возможно, Вы пользуетесь каким-то своим определением.

Comment: Да, усмотрение здесь вводного словосочетания противоречит распространённому определению г-жи Валгиной (... слова, словосочетания и предложения, _грамматически не связанные_ с членами предложения...) - у нас есть грамматическая связь через "который". Возможно, в уточнении нуждается само определение; в учебнике Бабайцевой есть пассаж с намёком на возможность грамматической связи (к сожалению, нет ссылок на конкретные материалы):

Comment: "Однако исследования последних лет обнаружили лексико-семантические и _грамматические средства_, с помощью которых осуществляется связь вводных и вставных компонентов с основной частью высказывания." http://sci.house/russkiy-yazyik/predlojeniya-oslojnennyie-vvodnyimi-vstavnyimi-68372.html

Comment: *"Однако исследования последних лет обнаружили лексико-семантические и грамматические средства, с помощью которых осуществляется связь вводных и вставных компонентов с основной частью высказывания.* Это противоречит определению вводного слова.

Comment: Нашёл ответ у Розенталя и пересмотрел свой ответ полностью; что касается отсутствия запятой, этому правилу следуют корректоры во всех книгах.

Comment: Вот это правильно. Хотя все равно не точно. У нас "не одни и те же слова". А "близкие" в лучше случае. **"По словам которых" - в принципе не может быть вводным.*** Только это было ясно и без Розенталя, непосредственно из определения.

Answer (score 0):

Как мне кажется, исходное предложение **не может быть грамотно оформлено в рамках данной грамматической конструкции.**

**Пояснение**

Смысл сообщения: К нам обратилась женщина, которая сказала, что их дом снесли. Или в более краткой форме: **К нам обратилась женщина, чей дом, по ее словам, снесли**. (Но здесь замена: их дом - её дом).

Вообще говоря, конструкции такого вида **встречаются в текстах** (чаще без обособления, иногда с обособлением), также при дословной передаче используются **кавычки**.

1) **Обособлять  сочетание "по словам которой"  в качестве вводного слова грамматически неверно**, так как теряется связь между предложениями (нет союза,  вводная часть не относится к предложению).  Поэтому **сочетание должно входит в состав предложения, служить союзным словом и не обособляться**.

2) Но тогда должно быть **исключено неверное понимание**: "по словам которой - это по указанию которой",  но в данном случае это сделать невозможно.

3) Что касается других примеров, то там  сочетание **также не обособляется**, но при этом значение вводности (как источник информации) должно ясно прочитываться из конструкции предложения. Также для ясности желательно использовать **дословную** передачу текста **с кавычками**.

**Примеры**

(1) Сам Д. И. Менделеев по болезни присутствовать на заседании не мог, и его работу доложил Н. А. Меншуткин, **по словам которого**, «сообщение не вызвало особого интереса или обмена мнений». (Обособление нежелательно).

(2) Не мог я, однако, соглашаться даже с таким авторитетом, как сам генерал Жоффр, **по словам которого** «это орудие способно разрешать любую задачу в полевой войне».

(3)В этом же духе высказывается М. Кубланов, **по словам которого** «формирующееся христианство могло группироваться вокруг личности некоего проповедника".

(4) Он ознакомился с рекламой пищевых добавок, замаскированной под формат беседы с врачом, **по словам которого** они помогают буквально от всех болезней.

Comment: Вам тот же вопрос. Вы грамматический разбор сделали? Откуда вообще эта идея рассуждать об оформлении, не обозначив структуру предложения? Если Вам она очевидно, покорнейше прошу поделиться. Мне нужна только она. Что вводные слова обособляются, я и так знаю.

Comment: Приведенное предложение некорректно - как же его разобрать? Это СПП в котором союзное слово обособили,  а  без обособления искажается семантика сообщения.

Comment: Ах вон оно что... ***Грамматически*** некорректно, позвольте поинтересоваться? Слово "обособление" - это вообще из другой темы. Про пунктуацию. Я согласен, что грамматически некорректное предложение нельзя разобрать корректно, но при чем тут обособление?

Comment: Союзное слово "который", с помощью которого соединяются главное и придаточное предложения,  не может относиться к вводному слову, поэтому "по словам которой" приходится считать обстоятельством.  Но в качестве необособленного обстоятельства оно может исказить смысл предложения. Вообще говоря, такие конструкции желательно применять только при явном цитировании, когда значение сочетания понимается только как источник информации, и никак иначе.

Comment: *Союзное слово "который", с помощью которого соединяются главное и придаточное предложения, не может относиться к вводному слову* - правильно. Осталось выяснить, с чего вы решили, что здесь вообще есть какие-то "вводные слова" или сочетания.

Comment: Сочетание "по словам которой" относится к тематике вводных слов (указание на источник информации),  и  эта семантика присутствует в предложении. Мы только  грамматически  не можем считать "по словам которой"  вводным словом, так как не имеем возможность  обособить  его от предложения.

Comment: Ну мало ли, что к тематики относится. Этого явно недостаточно, чтообы признать слова вводными вопрек4и определению. *Гражданка сообщила о снесении её дома. - тоже вводные по-вашему?*

Comment: В том -то и есть противоречивость такой конструкции, что по семантике сочетание вводное (обозначает источник информации),  а по грамматике оно  вводным быть не может.  Но переведенное в разряд обстоятельства,  вводное сочетание может приобрести другую семантику (в данном случае  - побуждение к действию), поэтому в таком виде это предложение воспринимается как некорректное. Соответственно,  употреблять такие конструкции нужно с осторожностью и желательно с дословным цитированием.

Comment: *В том -то и есть противоречивость такой конструкции* - да нет никакой противоречивости. Есть определение, которое ***исключает*** понимание союзного слова как части вводной конструкции. Противоречие - в голове у тех, кто этого не понимает. Тут интереснее другое. Видимо, методика преподавания страдает пустым натаскиванием, коли столько народу игнорирует первичные вещи (определения) ради каких-то примеров (пусть и из Розенталя) и вторичных свойств. Так вбили в голову некоторым, что указание на источник - обязательно вводное, что за деревьями леса не видно.

Answer (score 0):

Красота. Здесь слились воедино вводное "по словам" и союзное слово "которой".
Смысл: "...обратилась женщина сказать, что..."
Глагол "сказать" убежал и спрятался под вводным словом, заменяющим смысл самого глагола (по словам = сказать; женщина же сказала). Но чтобы соединить обе части сложного предложения, понадобилось союзное слово. 
Так что "по словам которой" можно рассматривать в качестве союзной конструкции. В книгах и СМИ такие конструкции встречаются нередко, запятой нет.
[Аристотель, "Метафизика"](https://books.google.com.ua/books?id=cL3-AgAAQBAJ&pg=PA249&lpg=PA249&dq=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85%22&source=bl&ots=jV7IV6EKxx&sig=zzIIosw6d0qz9TkTodMn4mtWeJo&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiN3q20lIXPAhXME5oKHQA4BMUQ6AEIODAG#v=onepage&q=%22%D0%BF%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BC%20%D0%BA%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%8B%D1%85%22&f=false)

Comment: На основании чего вы решили, что здесь есть вводные слова? Каким определение вы пользуетесь? Смысл меня сейчас интересует меньше всего, вопрос чисто грамматический.

Comment: Вопрос не задать, синтаксической связи нет, можно заменить... но вот совсем убрать уже нельзя - так как есть тесная связь со словом "которой". Вот с этого момента вводного слова уже нет, а есть союзная конструкция. В русском языке очень пластичная логика. Я бы сказала - женская.

Comment: Подождите с женской логикой ))). Есть вводные слова или нет? По определению. Что такое вводные слова? Если не знаете, я дам вам определение, которое мне нравится, но лучше, если это сделаете вы.

Comment: УЖЕ нет :-) Если бы "по её словам" - вполне вводное (не имеет, опять же, синтаксической связи - вопроса-то не задать, во-вторых, даёт сведение об источнике, заменимо синонимичным сочетанием, но (!) убрать совсем нельзя, а вводные слова можно полностью убирать, вот только смысл несколько меняется обычно). А вот в слиянии с "которой" уже нет вводной конструкции, и слова, которые могут быть вводными, становятся частью союзной же конструкции. Я не утверждаю, что в обсуждаемом изначальном примере есть вводн. сл. Как раз наоборот. Но само "по словам" - часто бывает вводным.

Comment: Послушайте, вы, имхо, на верном пути, только никак не можете сделать последний шаг. Дать определение вводному слову. Ну коли так, смотрите в тексте вопроса. Все жти ваши свойства - это непринципиальные вещи по сравнению с собственно определением.

Comment: Не вступая в синтаксическую связь с членами предложения, вводные слова входят в состав оного. Ну, чем не определение? Только в состав которого же из двух? Правда, здесь заминка и в том, что от одного предложения к другому вопрос задать затруднительно. Женщина обратилась... и???

Comment: *Не вступая в синтаксическую связь с членами предложения, вводные слова входят в состав оного. Ну, чем не определение?* Нет, это не определение в любом случае. Максиум - свойство, жа и то сомнительное. Переформулируйте так, чтобы из него было понятно, как отличить, вводные от не вводных. А лучше - не мучайтесь и посмотрите в любом учебнике. Где бы не посмотрели, все равно наличие союзного слова исключает трактовку оборота как вводного.

Comment: И всё-таки удивительно, что ошибку в заголовке вопроса до сих пор не исправили! Нонсенс? :-) Всех благ!

Comment: Так сказали бы сразу, чего вам не хватает для полного счастья - сразу бы и поправил.

Comment: Задеть никого не хотела, честное слово. Думала, что и так заметно, поправят.

Comment: Так нет, при чем тут "задеть"? Спасибо, что указали. Смелее сообщайте о таких вещах - при некоторой репутации сможете и сами править чужие опечатки. Принимается с благодарностью, это предусмотрено "форматом" ресурса.

Answer (score 0):

*В общем, удивительная история произошла. Меня в массе не поняли - не только тут, даже весьма маститые собеседники. И даже не попытались поправить по сути.*

*Не первый раз, да, но тут все настолько очевидно... Задачка для первого класса, если не для детсада. Не надо никаких знаний, кроме двух определений. 
Скажешь ребенку "Собака не ловит мышей. Мурка мышей ловит. Значит, Мурка - не собака" - и он поймёт, не будет вспоминать историю про дедушкиного Тузика, который щенком мышку то ли поймал, то ли нашел, то ли не мышку, то ли не Тузик. И то, что от Мурки не стоит ждать щенков, тоже поймет, хотя это и не главное даже*.

1. Вводные слова (*собаки*) не являются членами предложения (*не ловят мышей*)
2. Союзное слово (*Мурка*) является членом предложения (*ловит мышей*).
3. Следовательно, союзное слово (*Мурка*) не вводное и не часть вводного оборота (*не собака*).

Для особо продвинутых - бонус.

4. Оборот, содержащий союзное слово (*Мурка*), не является вводным (*собакой*) и поэтому не обособляется (*не приносит щенков*).

Простите, проще я не могу. Неужели даже это непонятно? Не согласиться (и возразить по существу), конечно, можно пытаться, но чтобы не понять вовсе...

По мне так куда проще, понятнее и правильнее по сути, чем кривые и совсем не бесспорные отсылки к единственной якобы аналогии из Розенталя. Причем даже среди тех, кто признает эту аналогию (и только её) нет единства в понимании, возможна ли двоякая пунктуация, т.е. запрещает ли Розенталь обособление в этих случаях или разрешает его как альтернативный вариант...