# Как объяснить отсутствие запятой?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, синтаксис, вводные-слова, спп

***Это человек, по мнению которого я совершил ошибку.***

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему после "которого" не ставится запятая? Совершенно очевидно, что ее там быть не должно(по аналогии с деепричастным оборотом, имеющим в своем составе союзное слово "который"), но как мне это максимально корректно объяснить? Можно ли обьяснить тем, что при изъятии "по мнению которого" поломается структура предложения? Заранее вам благодарен!!!

Comment: Об этом подробно было [здесь](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/426768/%d0%93%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%87%d0%b5%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%b9-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%80-%d0%9a-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%8c-%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%89%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc-%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%82%d0%be%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b9-%d0%b8%d1%85-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-%d1%81%d0%bd%d0%b5). И даже ссылка на Розенталя есть.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Это человек, по мнению которого я совершил ошибку.***

1. Сложный у вас, Игорь, вопрос.

С одной стороны,  обособить сочетание «по мнению которого» **вы не можете**, так как  союзное слово должно входить   в структуру придаточного предложения и обеспечивать его связь с главным, а при обособлении  этого сочетания  граматика СПП будет нарушена. Ну и при проверке путем изъятия вводного сочетания структура предложения действительно "поломается".

С другой стороны, вводное сочетание «по мнению кого-либо» практически всегда **обособляется**,  что можно видеть по примерам из Нацкорпуса.  Ситуация получается  "безвыходная", как и  в латинском афоризме: **держу волка за уши**: удержать не могу,  отпустить не могу тоже.

2. Попробуем из двух зол выбрать меньшее, то есть **обособлять** вводную конструкцию не будем. Но в этом предложении  стилистика такого  варианта  выглядит не лучшим образом. Кажется, что глагол управляет существительным: ошибаюсь по мнению (как будто по указанию).
3. А точно ли это вводное сочетание **обособляется всегда, без исключений**? Пожалуй, можно построить предложение без обособления, например: Это я по егО мнению всегда ошибаюсь, а другие так не считают.
4. Что ж, это выход, но надо немного перестроить предложение: ***Это человек, по мнению которого я  в данном случае совершил ошибку.***

При распространении предложения вводное сочетание  в меньшей степени «связано» с глаголом и имеет вид **необособленного наречного выражения** в роли детерминанта, после которого можно сделать небольшую произносительную паузу. И чем больше распространено предложение, тем лучше оно выглядит в стилистическом плане.

5. Интересно эта проблема решается **в Нацкорпусе.** Из 18 приведенных примеров вводное сочетание обособляется только в 5 случаях, например:

Иную концепцию школьной психологической службы предлагает Л. М. Фридман, **по мнению которого**, ее цели должны соответствовать главной цели школы на современном этапе. [ «Вопросы психологии», 2004]

Особенно непримиримым его противником выступал академик Н. Н. Моисеев, **по мнению которого** английское словосочетание sustanable development на русский язык следовало бы перевести как «допустимое развитие"... [В. П. Максаковский  (2003)]

Надо сказать, что предложения с обособлением выглядят в любом случае  странно. Я полагаю, что их следует признать **ошибочными**.